# Can we connect to remote IBM Infomix server from unix-putty using sqlcmd utility?

Tags: db2, sqlcmd

If yes, how do I connect to a remote IBM Infomix server and perform regular SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE queries using it?

I tried connecting to IBM Infomix server using sqlcmd as below,

sqlcmd -S --IP,--PORT -U --USERNAME -P --PASSCODE -d --DATABASE -i --INPUT_SQL_FILE -o --OUTPUT_FILE -h-1 -W -s--FIELD_SEPERATOR

But i couldnt connect to it..

Comment: Or is it specific for SQL server?

Comment: sqlcmd is for accessing Microsoft SQL-Server.   To use Informix databases from the shell command line, consider using the Informix dbaccess tool.

Comment: dbaccess tool or perl package, DBI is better to handle a scenario that involves huge data...